# RcppEigen LLT resulted in a vector of NaN

Tags: eigen, rcpp

I am trying the below RcppEigen function to solve a linear model. It compiled with no error but when I am applying it in R, it gave a vector of NaN values. I tried similar script with C++ without R and it worked perfectly. Any suggestions?

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP LLtSolve(const MatrixXd A, const MatrixXd b) {
    LLT<MatrixXd> llt;
    llt.compute(A);
    return Rcpp::wrap(llt.solve(b));
}
```

An example R code:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("Functions.cpp") # contains the previous LLtSolve function
n=1000
A=matrix(rnorm(n*n),nrow=n,ncol=n)
b=matrix(rnorm(n),nrow=n,ncol=1)
xxx=Sys.time()
f=LLtSolve(A,b)
Sys.time()-xxx
f[1:4]
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Show what matrix A and B contained.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works if you reduce `n`. For example:

```
> set.seed(42)

> n=500

> A=matrix(rnorm(n*n),nrow=n,ncol=n)

> b=matrix(rnorm(n),nrow=n,ncol=1)

> f=LLtSolve(A,b)

> min(f)
[1] -1.40086e+300

> max(f)
[1] 1.757129e+300
```

However, the minimum and maximum values are already quite extreme. When you increase the problem size further, you will reach the point where the result is no longer representable as a `double`:

```
> .Machine$double.xmax
[1] 1.797693e+308
> .Machine$double.xmin
[1] 2.225074e-308
```

This is not the case for a [sparse matrix](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html), e.g.:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Eigen/SparseLU>

using namespace Eigen;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
MatrixXd SparseSolve(const SparseMatrix<double>& A, const MatrixXd& b) {
  SparseLU<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
  solver.compute(A);
  if(solver.info()!=Success) {
    Rcpp::stop("decomposition failed");
  }
  MatrixXd x = solver.solve(b);
  if(solver.info()!=Success) {
    Rcpp::stop("solving failed");
  }
  return x;
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
n <- 10000
A <- Matrix::rsparsematrix(n, n, density = 0.2)
b <- matrix(rnorm(n), nrow = n, ncol = 1)
system.time(f <- SparseSolve(A,b))
f[1:4]
*/
```

Result:

```
> set.seed(42)

> n <- 10000

> A <- Matrix::rsparsematrix(n, n, density = 0.2)

> b <- matrix(rnorm(n), nrow = n, ncol = 1)

> system.time(f <- SparseSolve(A,b))
   user  system elapsed 
 80.640   0.524  81.163 

> f[1:4]
[1] -1.5994258 -0.6987579  1.3042338  0.1084376
```

Comment: Thanks Ralf, actually 1000 is just an example, I have a bigger matrix (100000 x 100000)

Comment: @user498036 Is that matrix densely populated? If my math isn‘t off, this means a 80GB matrix!

Comment: It is a sparse matrix, only 17-20% of it should have values other than zero.

Comment: @user498036 You are welcome. Please not that the conventional way to say "thank you" on SO is to up-vote/accept answers.